# Rewriting a where statement in SQL without using "unique"

Tags: mysql, sql

Rewrite the where clause

```
where unique (select title from course)
```

without using the unique construct

Comment: That's not a valid WHERE clause -- provide more info to get help, including database.

Comment: it is a valid clause, it is just not valid is sql.  However if you can give me the answer to return uniques titles tuples from course a course table is MySQL that would be a sufficient answer.

Comment: @Kyle, have you heard of **DISTINCT**? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: yes I have heard of it, how is it applied?  I'm trying to understand a homework assignment.

Comment: Have a look at the link provided.

Comment: Provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the related table(s), sample data & expected output if you want help.

Comment: Sorry I missed the link... This is my first time on the site and the formatting threw me off.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @OMG Ponies.  There is no create table statement because it is a homework problem.  It is just rewrite the statement to return unique results from any column in any table.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's not a valid Where clause even in MySql. There is no Unique function. If I'm wrong, I'd love to see a link to the docs that says otherwise.

Comment: Actually, on further research, `Unique(<subquery>)` is a valid predicate according to the SQL 92 specification. It's just not implemented in many database products as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the UNIQUE predicate is as follows:

```
1) Let T be the result of the <table subquery>.

2) If there are no two rows in T such that the value of each column
in one row is non-null and is equal to the value of the cor-
responding column in the other row according to Subclause 8.2,
"<comparison predicate>", then the result of the <unique predi-
cate> is true; otherwise, the result of the <unique predicate>
is false.
```

(*Revision*)
Thus, the equivalent results of the Unique predicate as you have written it would be:

```
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From Course
                    Where Title Is Not Null
                    Group By Title
                    Having Count(*) > 1
                    )
```

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - First, performance is never mentioned as part of the equation. Second, the original also has no correlation to the base query. We are only given a Where clause and never told whats in the From clause. So, purely based on what is given it is accurate. I.e., if our db product supported the Unique predicate, since it also does not have a correlation to the outer query it would either return all rows or no rows.

Comment: @Richard: Being a homework it can mean anything, I think. It may just be an exercise.

Comment: I don't think you are handling `NULL` values correctly. Re-read your clause 2) again, noting that all `NULL`'s will `GROUP` together.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - You are assuming that the performance metrics on the Unique predicate would be any better. We have no way of knowing. As Andriy M stated, it's homework so it's meant to be a thought exercise.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - One more item, I cannot imagine ever using the Unique predicate without using its correlated form for the very reason you gave. What sense would it mean?

Comment: @onedaywhen - I think you are correct. I think Nulls have to be excluded. Have updated my solution.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - Perhaps, I need to rephrase, "I cannot every imagine using the Unique predicate w/o using a correlated form. **However**, that is the example given to us". Thus, the original example is flawed *if used in practice* which it is not; it is homework. Thus, performance has no bearing. Second, in some dbs correlated subqueries perform quite well actually. It depends on the optimizer and the query. For example, I have found that SQL Server handles correlated subqueries significantly better than MySQL.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - It should be noted that my solution is not a correlated subquery. It is a subquery (with no correlation). So, it would actually perform quite well. Better than using All in fact. Would it would return logical results? Well, it would return results as logical as the original question ;->

Comment: To summarize, I make the point that this question as given makes no sense at all IRL; the performance, were the OP to extend this solution to a correlated subquery will be poor (in MySQL) - that form should be tackled as a simple group by (`having count(*) =1`). Dealing with SO users and homework questions, I doubt the problem domain is as stated in the question, so an answer to the question verbatim will be "too localized" if it is possible to vote to close an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` clause returns unique values for the column(s) specified in the `SELECT` clause.  Depending on the data, as the number of columns increases -- so does the possibility that there will be duplicate values in a single column because other columns contain unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       c.title
  FROM COURSE c
```

...will return a unique list of titles.  But if you add columns that can have different values for each title:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       c.title,
       c.instructor
  FROM COURSE c
```

...the title column will likely hold duplicates when 2+ instructors teach the same course title because `DISTINCT` returns unique rows across all columns involved.

The GROUP BY clause is another alternative:

```
  SELECT c.title
    FROM COURSE c
GROUP BY c.title
```

...will produce the same result set as the first example using `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 1 = ALL(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course GROUP BY title)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UNIQUE keyword test for Absence of Duplicate Tuples**

- The unique construct tests whether a subquery has any duplicate
  tuples in its result.
- The unique construct evaluates to “true” on an empty set.

consider below data set with *name* and *age*,

```
sameera___ 20

john_______ 22

mac_______26

john_______22
```

if we use **unique** keyword for *age* to this instance, *result* would be,

```
sameera___20

mac______26
```

but if we use **distinct** keyword for *age*, we get,

```
sameera___20

john______22

mac______26
```

by removing **only** duplicates but **not** the **original one**.